# Terminating app due to uncaught exception, reason: 'attempt to delete row 3 from section 1 which only contains 0 rows before the update'

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, height

I am trying to reload my TableView but I am getting this exception "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 3 from section 1 which only contains 0 rows before the update'".

Below is my code :-

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if statusTableView == tableView {

        return ModelAssessStatus.sharedInstance.arrType.count
    } 

    else {
         if !sections[section].expanded {
            return 0
        }

         else {
            return sections[section].names.count
        }

        //return sections[section].names.count
        /*if sections[section].expanded == true {
            return sections[section].names.count
        }

        else {
            return 0
        }*/
    }
}. 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var expandableCategoryCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExpandableCategoryCell") as? ExpandableCategoryCell

        if expandableCategoryCell == nil {
            var nib:Array = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ExpandableCategoryCell", owner: self, options: nil)!
            expandableCategoryCell = nib[0] as? ExpandableCategoryCell
        }

        expandableCategoryCell?.selectionStyle = .none
        expandableCategoryCell?.labelName.text = sections[indexPath.section].names[indexPath.row]
        return expandableCategoryCell!

        //return UITableViewCell()

    }. 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    if tableView == self.expandableTableView {
        return 60
    }

    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    if tableView == self.expandableTableView {
        return 0
    }

    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    if tableView == expandableTableView {

        let cell = self.expandableTableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "ExpandableHeaderView")
        let header = cell as! ExpandableHeaderView

        header.customInit(title: sections[section].categoryType, section: section, delegate: self, isSelected: sections[section].fullSelected)

        if sections[section].expanded {
            header.imgArrow?.image = UIImage(named : "down_Arow")//.transform = (header.imgArrow?.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi)))!
        }

        else {
            header.imgArrow?.image = UIImage(named : "error")
        }

        return cell
    }

    else {
        return UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
    }
}

//Height For Raw at indexPath
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if statusTableView == tableView {
        return 50
    }

    else {

        if (sections[indexPath.section].expanded) {
            return 60
        }

        else {
            return 0
        }
    }
  }
}


extension PeerCategoryStatusVC : expandableHeaderViewDelegate {
func toggleSections(header: ExpandableHeaderView, section: Int) {

    sections[section].expanded = !sections[section].expanded

    //expandableTableView.reloadData()
    expandableTableView.beginUpdates()

    for index in 0..<sections[section].names.count {
        expandableTableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row : index, section : section)], with: .automatic)
    }

    expandableTableView.endUpdates()

    //self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
  }
}.
```

Here Begin Update and End Update TableView. 
I am trying to reload tableView but don't know why I am getting exception.

If I will keep same number of rows then constraints issue is coming.

Is there anything which I have to add ?

Comment: Because you are changing the number of rows returned by `numberOfRows(inSection:)`, as soon as you change the expanded state for the relevant section the necessary rows are “automatically” inserted or deleted. You just need to reload the section. Right now, when you collapse a section the number of rows in that section becomes 0, so when you attempt to reload a row in that section you get an exception.

Comment: Oh You mean I have to reload only section ?

Comment: Yes, try that, if that doesn’t help indicate which line in your code is throwing the exception

Comment: OK Let me check it once.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 0 from section 1 which only contains 0 rows before the update'

Comment: I am getting same exception.

Comment: expandableTableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: section)], with: .automatic)

Comment: I thought that might happen. If a section contains 0 rows then it needs to be removed. You either need to adjust the number of sections returned by `numberOfSections` or ensure that the section always includes at least 1 row.

Comment: If I will do this then Height becoming 0 and constraints error is coming.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155676/discussion-between-paulw11-and-kishor0011).

Comment: You need to have something in the cell.  You can’t have expanding sections with a section header alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just fix the same exception. It's mainly because you call `reloadRows(at: with:)` with indexPath(s) whose `row` is larger than the total row count.

Comment: Then how you fixed ?

Comment: Add a if statement or find out why `row` is larger than row count. check if you reload the tableview/section in time when your data source changes.